# Assign jQuery datepicker to div element and get the value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I want to show a datepicker using jQuery when user click on some text, and after the user select the date on datepicker, I can get the value from the date picker as javascript variable. My code is like this:

```
<div id="datepicker-container" style="display: none;">
    <div id="select-delivery-date-input"> </div>
</div>
<a id="show-datepicker">Select Delivery Date</a>
<script>
  $("#show-datepicker").click(function(){
      $("#datepicker-container").show();
  });
  $('#select-delivery-date-input').datepicker({ 
      dateFormat:'yy-m-d',
      minDate: new Date(),
  });
</script>
```

The problem is when the datepicker popup, when I tried to select the date on datepicker popup it won't close the datepicker popup.

[Fiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/nh6eoj03/372/)

Comment: Could you provide a jsfiddle?

Comment: @Mazz see my updated answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use datepicker's [`onSelect`](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-onSelect) option:

> Called when the datepicker is selected. The function receives the selected date as text and the datepicker instance as parameters.

Then you can use jQuery [`hide()`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/).

Here a live sample:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#show-datepicker").click(function(){ 
    $("#datepicker-container").show();
  });
  $('#select-delivery-date-input').datepicker({ 
    dateFormat:'yy-m-d',
    minDate: new Date(),
    onSelect: function(selectedDate){
      console.log(selectedDate);
      $("#datepicker-container").hide();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div id="datepicker-container" style="display: none;">
  <div id="select-delivery-date-input"> </div>
</div>
<a id="show-datepicker">Select Delivery Date</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please find below the altered code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var selectedDate;

  $("#show-datepicker").click(function(){ 
      $("#datepicker-container").show();
  });
  $('#select-delivery-date-input').datepicker({ 
      dateFormat:'yy-m-d',
      minDate: new Date(),
      onSelect: function(date){
      selectedDate = date;
      alert(selectedDate);//selected date is assigned to date1, you can use date1 anywhere
      $("#datepicker-container").hide();
    }
     }
   );
});
```